# JQuery each function to multiply numbers of item

Tags: jquery, each

Am trying to calculate total amount of item using jquery each function but it doesn't work. Please can someone assist me on how to get it right.

```js
$('.qty_value').on('change', function(){
    var new_qty = $(this).val();
    $('.item1').attr('data-order-qty', new_qty);
    var subamount, sqty, samt;
    $('.cart_items').each(function(){
      sqty = $(this).attr('data-order-qty');
      samt = $(this).attr('data-order-price');
      subamount += samt * sqty;
    //alert(subamount);     
    });
    alert(subamount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart_items item1" data-order-qty="2" data-order-price="100">Item 1</div>
    <div class="cart_items item2" data-order-qty="1" data-order-price="10">Item 2</div>
    <div class="cart_items item3" data-order-qty="4" data-order-price="50">Item 3</div>
```

The above query alert `NAN`, but if i remove the plus it will return the amount for the first item only.

Comment: @u_mulder when i show alert inside the loop it will print all but one by one. I want it to plus all the amount and return it once

Comment: Oh, dude.  You are not initializing subamount to anything.  null += anything will most likely be NaN.  Initialize it to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init your `subamount` with a 0 value:

```
var subamount = 0, sqty, samt;
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value is stored as string. Initializing sum variable to number (0) converts the values into numbers.

To be more sure, use `Number()` or `parseInt()` while calculating mathematical equations.

```js
$('#calcSum').on('click', function(){

    var new_qty = $(this).val();
    var subamount = 0;
    
    $('.item1').attr('data-order-qty', new_qty);
    
    $('.cart_items').each(function(){
      var current = $(this);
      subamount += Number(current.data('order-qty')) * Number(current.data('order-price'));
    });
    
    alert(subamount);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart_items item_1" data-order-qty="2" data-order-price="100">Item 2</div>
<div class="cart_items item_2" data-order-qty="1" data-order-price="10">Item 2</div>
<div class="cart_items item_3" data-order-qty="4" data-order-price="50">Item 3</div>

<button type="button" id="calcSum"> add </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variable you are trying to += to

```js
var subamount1;
var subamount2 = 0;

subamount1 += '1' * '2';
subamount2 += '1' * '2';

console.log(subamount1, subamount2);
```